# The repository pattern and LinqToSql methods

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I have an object that encapsulates a linq to sql data context.

It has a method `IQuerable<T> FromStore<T>` that allows me to get my entities from the appropriate table via linq to sql.

I also have call-through methods to call functions on the data context.

The problem I have now is that I can't use those pass through methods within where clauses because there's no translation to sql. I understand why this is happening, but how can I work around it?

---

Example code:

In my repository class:

```
public class AquaReportsRepository : LinqToSqlRepository<int>, IAquaReportsRepository
{
    public bool IsPhysicalItem(string itemNumber)
    {
        return _UnderlyingDataContext.Aqua_IsPhysicalItem(itemNumber) ?? true;
    }
}
```

Trying to access data from it:

```
from part in Repository.FromStore<Parts>()
where !(Repository.IsPhysicalItem(part.Item)) // eek, not translation to sql
select part.ItemNumber;
```

---

In the past, where I've needed a simple property on a data object, calculated from another property i've used [QueryMap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32968/QueryMap-Custom-translation-of-LINQ-expressions) to translate the property into an equivalent expression, however I don't think I can do that here as I need to access a datacontext method.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Read the example for point 1. Use the code in QueryMap, making the changes in bold below.

---

Right, I've managed to work around this using some slight modifications to [QueryMap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32968/QueryMap-Custom-translation-of-LINQ-expressions)

There were 2 things I needed to get working:

1. Figure out how to tell querymap to call a method that uses the data context?
2. Figure out how to get querymap to pick up the attribute defined on a class, when being accessed via an interface.

The first part was fairly simple:

```
private static readonly ExpressionMethod<Func<AquaReportsRepository, string, bool>> _IsPhysicalItem =
    ExpressionMethod.Create((AquaReportsRepository ardc, string i) => ardc._AquaReportsDC.Aqua_IsPhysicalItem(i) ?? true);

[MapToExpression("_IsPhysicalItem")]
public bool IsPhysicalItem(string itemNumber)
{
    return _IsPhysicalItem.Invoke(this, itemNumber);
}
```

The key here is to simply use a function that takes the object itself as the first argument (`AquaReportsRepository` in this case) in addition to the normal other argument(s).

The second part however required some (fairly minor) changes to `MappedQueryVisitor.cs`. in both cases only a single if statement (with statements inside!).

**Replace the existing `GetLambda` method with this**:

```
private LambdaExpression GetLambda(Expression receiver, MemberInfo member) {

    LambdaExpression exp;
    if(!_mappings.TryGetValue(member, out exp)) {
        exp = _mappingLookup(member);
        if(null == exp) {
            var attr = (MapToExpressionAttribute) member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MapToExpressionAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();

            // Added by me to deal with interfaces
            if (null == attr)
            {
                if (null != receiver)
                {
                    // member could be an interface's member, so check the receiver.object type
                    if (receiver.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
                    {
                        var receiverType = ((ConstantExpression)receiver).Value.GetType();

                        var receiverMemberInfo = receiverType.GetMembers().Where(mi => mi.Name == member.Name).SingleOrDefault();

                        if (null != receiverMemberInfo)
                        {
                            attr = (MapToExpressionAttribute)receiverMemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MapToExpressionAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
                            member = receiverMemberInfo;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            if(null != attr) {
                exp = GetLambdaFromAttribute(receiver, member.DeclaringType, attr);
            }
        }
        _mappings.Add(member, exp);
    }
    return exp;
}
```

This change means that if we have a `member` `MethodInfo` object representing an interfaces method we will recognise that and try and get the actual `MethodInfo` of the concrete type we're working with (defined by the constant expression).

Now it correctly picks up the `MapToExpressionAttribute` attribute on the implementing class, given the `MemberInfo` of an interface.

The next issue though is with `VisitMethodCall`, where having got the replacement expression to invoke from the attribute it fails because the argument expression is the interface type, by the method we're invoking requires the implementing class.

This last code change corrects that.

**Change the `CollectArguments` method to this**:

```
private static IEnumerable<Expression> CollectArguments(MethodCallExpression m) {
    IEnumerable<Expression> args = m.Arguments;
    if (!m.Method.IsStatic)
    {
        var objectExpression = m.Object;

        // Added by me, to deal with interfaces
        if (objectExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
        {
            var objectConstExpression = ((ConstantExpression)objectExpression);

            if (objectConstExpression.Type.IsInterface)
            {
                objectExpression = Expression.Constant(objectConstExpression.Value);
            }
        }

        args = Enumerable.Repeat(objectExpression, 1).Concat(args);
    }
    return args;
}
```